# How to Unit Test Graphql Resolver functions created using apollo-resolvers

Tags: mocha.js, graphql, chai, apollo-server

I have created resolver**s(userresolver.js)** using '**apollo-resolvers**' npm module as below.

```
import { createResolver } from 'apollo-resolvers';
import {  isInstance } from 'apollo-errors';

const baseResolver = createResolver(
  null,
  (root, args, context, error) => isInstance(error) ? error : new UnknownError()
);



const users = baseResolver.createResolver(
  (parent, args, { models, me } ) => {
         return Object.values(models.users);
  }
);

export default {
  Query: {
    users
  }
}
```

;

These also work fine when I test the queries after starting the server.

I now want to do unit testing of the resolver functions.

I am not sure how to do that. Can someone help me on how to unit test the resolver functions. I am using **mocha with cha**i for testing my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [easygraphql-tester](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester), it has a method that'll help you to test the resolvers.

[Here](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester#testing-the-resolvers) is the documentation of it.

### Example:

#### Resolver

```js
"use strict";

const license = (__, args, ctx) => {
  const { key } = args;

  return {
    id: "1234",
    body: "This is a test license",
    description: `This is a description with key ${key}`
  };
};

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    license
  }
};
```

#### Test

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const EasyGraphQLTester = require("easygraphql-tester");

const resolvers = require("../resolvers");
const schemaCode = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, "..", "schema.gql"),
  "utf8"
);

describe("Test resolvers", () => {
  let tester;
  beforeAll(() => {
    tester = new EasyGraphQLTester(schemaCode, resolvers);
  });

  it("should return expected values", async () => {
    const query = `
      query GET_LICENSE($key: String!) {
        license(key: $key) {
          id
          body
          description
        }
      }
    `;

    const args = {
      key: "1234"
    };

    const result = await tester.graphql(query, {}, {}, args);
    expect(result.data.license.id).to.be.eq("1234");
    expect(result.data.license.body).to.be.eq("This is a test license");
    expect(result.data.license.description).to.be.eq(
      `This is a description with key ${args.key}`
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this addresses the requirement. for unit testing resolvers code . Seems like it is for integration/E2E testing.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/42m2rx71j4) can be useful!